# I want to have one cell that can result in 3 different values based on it's own value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am attempting to solve for a business problem via an excel document.  In this document, I am trying to solve for:

"Within a cell, If the value = Option 1, then Answer 1.  If the value = Option 2, then Answer 2".

Here's an example:

```
Cell B6 = 2
Cell C6 = 1
Cell D6 = 0

Cell B18 = Either B6, C6 or D6
Cell B19 = I want to say the following: if B18=B6, then show "12".  If B18=C6, then show "6".  If B18=D6, then show "0".
```

How can I solve for B19?

Comment: What formulas have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The long way would be to use nested `IF`s:

```
=IF(B18=B6, 12, IF(B18=C6, 6, 0))
```

But you can also use `CHOOSE` with a little creativity, since the values in B6, C6 and D6 are 1 unit away from each other:

```
=CHOOSE(B18+1,0,6,12)
```

But there's an even more interesting formula, since B6*6=12, C6*6=6 and D6*6=0:

```
=B18*6
```

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately the =IF(B21=B6,12,IF(B21=C6, 6)) didn't work.  

When utilizing that, in the instance where B21 DOES equal C6, I am still returned the value of "12".

Also, B6, C6 and D6 likely won't be just one unit away every time.  So I'm not sure if that'll work.  But thank you for that introduction to the CHOOSE function!

Comment: Ugh, apologies.  It was a user error on my end.

This worked famously.  Thank you, so much!!

Comment: @Miguelito Awesome :)